# Add a code to Magento 2 checkout page . where to write code?

Tags: magento, magento2

I want to add following code in my magento 2 checkout page . I don't want to create a new extension for that . Please see my code below

```
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
     
        if($observer->getEvent()->getMethodInstance()->getCode()=="cashondelivery"){
            $checkResult = $observer->getEvent()->getResult();
            $checkResult->setData('is_available', true);
        }else{
            
            $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
            $cart = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart'); 
            $items = $cart->getItems();
            $flag = 0;
            $count=0;
            foreach($items as $item){
                
                $attribute1 = $item->getProduct()->getData('otherthancod');
                 if($attribute1){
                    $flag++;
                    $count++;
                }else{
                    $flag--;
                }
            }
            
            if($flag == $count){
                        $checkResult = $observer->getEvent()->getResult();
                        $checkResult->setData('is_available', true); 
            }else{
                        $checkResult = $observer->getEvent()->getResult();
                        $checkResult->setData('is_available', false); 
            }
            
        }
    }
```

**In which page i can write this code ?**

Please help .

Answer (score 1):

You could use

https://www.silksoftware.com/magento-module-creator/magento2-module-creator.php

to generate the extension. You would still have to override the Controller with the 'preference' tag in di.xml . Overriding PHP code is not possible without a custom module.